# Simple Bisimulation algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Is there a simple algorithm to calculate the maximal bisimulation relation of a graph/two graphs?
With simple i mean very easy implementation, complexity is not that important for us in this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coarsest bisimulation has a well known greatest fixed point characterisation. This greatest fixed point characterisation gives you a simple algorithm to calculate bisimulation quotients. There are quite a few immediate improvements you can make to this algorithm. A reference that contains most of these details is [Joost Pieter Katoen's lecture on bisimulation minimization](http://www-i2.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/i2/fileadmin/user_upload/documents/AMC09/amc09_lec2.pdf). If you need more detail, I suggest looking at the book

> [Principles of Model Checking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026202649X), Christel Baier and Joost-Pieter Katoen.